# How to fix error in delete confirmation message in php

Tags: php, confirmation

I have some PHP code that I'm trying to add a delete confirmation. But is causing an error...

```
$arr_data[$array_pos][] = 'a href="delete.php?pid='.$row['pid'].'"
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete')">delete<';
```

The `onclick` code is causing the problem.  With my very limited (zero!) knowledge, I cannot find a fix, so any help would be appreciated.

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete')"
```

(I removed the hyperlink HTML code so it will display)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotes.

```
$arr_data[$array_pos][] = '<a href="delete.php?pid=' . $row['pid'] . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete?\')">Delete</a>';
```